# How to delete event from iCal added from my app.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calendar, icalendar

I'm developing an app in which when user add any event as his favorite, I'm adding that event to iCal but how do i remove that event from iCal if user removes that particular event from his favorite.?

Here is my code:

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[self.parentDetailArray valueForKey:@"start_time_num"] intValue]];
            NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
            [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            NSString *dateString=[dateformatter stringFromDate:date];

             EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

             if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) 
{
 [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
             if (granted){
             //---- codes here when user allow your app to access theirs' calendar.

             EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
             event.title     = title;
             event.startDate = date;
             event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:1000 sinceDate:event.startDate];

             [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
             NSError *err;
             [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

// Here I'm trying to get the identifier of that event but m getting only (null)
             self.str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
             [self.arrayofEventId addObject:self.str];

             //[self performCalendarActivity:eventStore];
             }else
             {
             //----- codes here when user NOT allow your app to access the calendar.
             }
             }];
             }
             else {
             //---- codes here for IOS < 6.0.
             EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
             event.title     = @"Testing for calendar";

             event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
             NSLog(@"%@",event.startDate);
             [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
             NSError *err;
             [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
             //[self performCalendarActivity:eventStore];
             }
```

How do i get the event identifier n remove that particular event from iCal. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could write all app generated event ID's to file and then load them back up next time the app loads. This way you can keep track of which events your app created. Then you may want to try this method:

```
- (BOOL)removeEvent:(EKEvent *)event span:(EKSpan)span commit:(BOOL)commit error:(NSError **)error
```

Save with this:

```
NSString *id = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
```

Remove with this:

```
EKEvent *event = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:id];

NSError *error = nil;
[eventStore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
```

Apple has documentation on the EKEventStore [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: i have stored all the event ID's in an Mutable array and I'm storing  that array to file so that i can keep track of all the event added by my app. but when i'm using this remove method it's giving me this message in console. "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error 268435459 - (ipc/send) invalid destination port).